# fullcalendar show event based on checkbox value

Tags: jquery, checkbox, fullcalendar

I am having trouble showing/hiding a set of events based on a checkbox checked or not.  I don't understand how to use the `eventRender` attribute of jquery plugin FullCalendar.
I get data from the database and it displays on the calendar fine.  All checkboxes are checked.  If the user unchecks the checkbox, I want that set of events to be hidden.  If checked, show.
This is my markup:

```
<div id="groups" style="float:left; width: 200px; height: 100px">
    <div style="border: 2px solid black; background-color: lightblue">
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="e1" id="e1" value="1" />Warehouse Group</label>     
    </div>
    <div style ="border: 2px solid black; background-color: red">
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="e2" id="e2" value="2" />Interface Group</label>     
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    titleFormat: {month: 'MMMM'},              
    defaultView: 'month',                 
    editable: false,
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEvents", "Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];                     
                $(doc).each(function () { 
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),  
                        start: $(this).attr('start'), 
                        end: $(this).attr('end'),
                        id: $(this).attr('id'),
                        description: $(this).attr('description'),
                        color: $(this).attr('color'), 
                        textColor: 'black'
                    });

                });
                callback(events);
                } ,                                                                   
            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error fetching events!")
            }
        });
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        //THIS IS WHERE I AM CONFUSED...
        //Render the event if the 'value' attribute of a checked checkbox
        //equals the description value of the event, show the event.
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).checked) {
                if ($(this).val() == event.description)
                {
                    show event
                }
            }          
        });         
    }
     });

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});
```

**UPDATE**
Changed the render function so the code executes.  But I don't understand what has to be returned in this function to show the event?

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    if ( $( this ).is( ":checked" ) ) {
                        if ($(this).val() == event.description)
                        {
                            alert('title: ' + event.title);
                            return event.title;
                        }
                    }          
                });
```

**UPDATE**
I am trying to pass in the group IDs of the groups that are to be displayed.  It works on initialization but when I uncheck one of the groups, the array still has 2 items in it instead of one.
This is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
var groupSelectedArray = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        groupSelectedArray.push($(this).val());

    }
});
var groupData = { selectedGroups: groupSelectedArray };

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    titleFormat: {month: 'MMMM'},              
    defaultView: 'month',                 
    editable: false,

    events: function (start, end, groupSelectedArray, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEvents", "Home")',
            data: JSON.stringify(groupData),//{ selectedGroups: groupSelectedArray },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];                     
                $(doc).each(function () { 
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),  
                        start: $(this).attr('start'), 
                        end: $(this).attr('end'),
                        id: $(this).attr('id'),
                        description: $(this).attr('description'),
                        color: $(this).attr('color'), 
                        textColor: 'black'
                    });

                });
                callback(events);
                } ,                                                                   
            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error fetching events!")
            }
        });
    }
```

This is when the box is unchecked:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
            var groupSelectedArray = [];

            $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    groupSelectedArray.push($(this).val());

                }
            });
            var groupData = { selectedGroups: groupSelectedArray };

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        });
```

Why is the groupSelectedArray not getting reset to 1 item when the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: your $(this).val() of the checkbox is not getting the checkbox text but the value. so in this case 1 or 2.

Comment: if you want to get the text in your case, use this instead
if($(this).val()[0].nextSibling.nodeValue == event.description)

Comment: how do I show the event?

Comment: I am comparing the value of the checkbox with the description of the event which is the ID of the group.  The ID will be either 1 or 2.  If the Checkbox is checked and has a value of 1 it is compared to the event's description value which is either 1 or 2.  If the description matches the value, show the event.  The events are shown even if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: I changed the if statement for a checked value and my alert shows the title of the event.  But how are events shown or hidden?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://www.mikesmithdev.com/demo-fullcalendar-with-event-filtering/

Comment: So in order to show or hide a set of events they have to come from different event sources?

Comment: you should store the events in a separate array and then add them based on the checkbox using the fullCalendar('addEventSource', newSource[0])

Comment: I am refetching the data in my update above. Is that what you mean?  The selected group array is always 2 items even when the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Event Render Callback to hide / show events:

```
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                if ( $( this ).is( ":checked" ) ) {
                    if ($(this).val() == event.description)
                    {
                        // Show event: return the given event
                        alert('title: ' + event.title);
                        return event.title;
                    }
                }

                //  Hide event: return false
                return false;

            });
```

that's all